# GNU grep line buffered not working on MacOS

Tags: macos, grep, adb

I am trying to grep the output from a continuously running program, on Linux I just used --line-buffered, but it is not working on macOS and I am at a loss as to what to try next.

```
macbook:~$ ggrep --version
ggrep (GNU grep) 3.3
Packaged by Homebrew
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others; see
<https://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
macbook:~$ adb logcat | ggrep --line-buffered e

  <no output until I ctrl-C>
```

Comment: does mac have option to run command prefixed with `stdbuf -o0' ?

Comment: Line buffering is the default if output goes to a terminal. You need to check how `adb` buffers its output.

Comment: I get the same behaviour with something like tail -f

Comment: I like turtles.